# Can I get un-bullied?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39481081/2706707

I answered the OP's question about his code. OP flagged it as correct, but more than that, *it is correct*. Complexity is about loops. Yes, recursion is a form of loop, but OP's code had nothing to do with recursion.

User **Jerry Coffin** downvotes my response and comments with wild straw-man and direct personal derision.

My response to him was deleted. (I am sick of straw man crap.) I *also* edited my post to be *explicit* that recursion counts as a loop when dealing with complexity.

Mr Coffin again responds, this time with snobbery and non-sequitor: I was not taking for granted OP's knowledge of recursion -- It was *Mr Coffin* who first mentioned it!

I again responded, counting these exact same points.

So, **why have my responses been deleted while his abusive commentary remains?**

<sub>I come to SO to help out. If I make a mistake, fine. I'll fix it.</sub>
<sub>I don't come to SO so some small-minded bully can pretend he's smarter than me and somehow disabuse me of a reasonable ability to protest him.</sub>

I can live with discourse; allow one party to silence another without recourse on a public forum and it is no longer honest discourse.

Thank you for hearing my complaint.

Comment: That is what flags are for. Flag his comment and move on.

Comment: The moderator might not have read the whole conversation, considering his messages hadn't been flagged yet but yours were. Words like "crap" and "morons" are usually a good sign that that user isn't participating constructively and the comments need deleted. You just need to point out that the other user isn't participating constructively either (in a flag) so the moderator will look at them more closely. It really is that simple.

Comment: You can smell the blatant hyperbole of this post from three miles away, without even reading it

Comment: unfortunately this is a pattern that has cropped up in the last couple of months, I am documenting my same experiences with screenshots and evidence for a similar post, sorry you are not alone in this experience.

Comment: @OP AFAIK mods don't see flagged comments in context. They see just the flagged comments. If you got flagged but didnt flag, then this is working as expected. It's not always easy but 'be nice' applies all the time, even if others aren't being nice

Comment: @Telkitty is trying to trick you into entering a den of hungry man eating wolves.  You will be consumed.  Don't do it.

Comment: What, no. We are a  group of cute cuddly puppies (and kittens) eagerly waiting for new users to share our love with. Look, we are so nice, even a  couple of SE staff like to hang around with us. In fact, they are in the C++ lounge right now! That's how nice and irresistable the lounge really is @Will

Comment: For context, the first comment that Jerry posted was this: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32833361#32833361 I don't know what happened after that though.

Comment: Last year, I wrote [The decline of Stack Overflow : How trolls have taken over your favorite programming Q&A site](https://medium.com/@johnslegers/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d), explaining how trolls appear to be running this site. With more than 120,000 views, I clearly seem to have struck a nerve... and questions like yours only illustrate how little has improved since then!

Answer (score 25):

Without debating the exact sequence of events (which I doubt I could reconstruct correctly if I tried), let me start by saying that if you felt bullied, I do sincerely apologize for that. It certainly wasn't my intent.

Rather the contrary, when I wrote my original comment, it was meant quite light-heartedly. You had written a simple, straightforward answer to a question that a lot of people find confusing. I thought with just a little editing, it could become a really good answer. If I hadn't seen that possibility, I probably wouldn't have bothered writing a comment at all--I'd just have downvoted and moved on instead.

For almost any given question, there are two types of possible answers. One is just an answer to the exact question that was posted. These can be somewhat useful, but aren't really a huge contribution.

Other answers cover entire classes of questions. Sometimes they do that by writing the equivalent of a small book on the subject (search [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) for some examples). Others cut to the heart of the matter, taking a subject many people find difficult, and keeping it simple enough that people can easily grasp a basic principle and learn something from it in a way that will really stick with them (and don't get me wrong: I'm not saying the C++-faq answers are bad--just that many cover a lot of details).

As it was written, your answer was at least a reasonable stab at the first. It was probably enough to get the person who asked the question at least roughly on the right track. At the same time, it left out enough that others who had similar questions could easily read it as being an answer to the questions they had--but in a fair number of cases, it would be a *wrong* answer to those questions.

I thought, however, that I saw there an answer that, with just a little editing, could become one of the second sort of answer, so *lots* of people who had questions about computational complexity in general could find that answer via search engines and such, and use it to gain an understanding of that subject at a truly fundamental level, so it's no longer just answering that *exact* question, but hundreds or thousands of similar ones.

Summary:

1. Please don't take my comment as a personal attack on you. It really wasn't intended that way at all.
2. When writing answers, do try to keep in mind that a good answer isn't aimed *just* at the person who wrote this particular question, but also at everybody else who might find that question/answer via search engines and such.

Comment: I love reading a thoughtful and considerate answer like this on Meta - thanks Jerry!

Comment: Well said! When I provide unsolicited advice on topics I'm well-acquainted with, it is often necessary to explain that the **advice is not a personal attack**. All of us go through the first few steps of mastery, where our sense of worth is so tied to a new skill that corrections are personal insults. But as we mature we learn to detach ourselves from the skill. It's an enjoyable experience to help somebody have a eureka moment, and unfortunate that misunderstandings can spoil those moments

Comment: I call utter BS revisionism so you and your friends here can pat yourselves on the back about how fair and balanced you are. Hint: if you really did believe all this, you wouldn't have written your comments as offensively as you did, nor would you have sought to remove my responses to your abusive, illogical nonsense. But hey, no one cares except to protect their social cohort, because their feelings get hurt. (Boo hoo!) Oh, and be sure to delete this comment too, since you cannot stand to accept any honest constructive criticism. I'm so sick of dealing with intellectually dishonest people.

Comment: @Dúthomhas You've been here 3 years, and appear to be a professional programmer; there's no reason for you to be hurt by a comment. The removal of your comments protects you from appearing irrationally angry -- and exaggerate Jerry's harshness. It's not the end of the world, and you'll have many more good answers in the future. Don't worry so much about internet points and the chance to look like *The Last Defender of Human Insight* (which is often perceived as arrogance). If you're just having a bad day I'll seriously buy you a coffee!

Comment: TIL Calling "utter BS revisionism" is constructive feedback.

Comment: Mmm. Just read the two later comments. I'll join in on the coffee. Good idea. Cheers!